# Is there a startSearch() function equivalent that can be used in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-googleapiclient

I am developing a map in a fragment using mapView. The fragment consists of a mapView and a searchBar(mancj.materialsearchbar). I tried using startSearch() in the OnSearchActionListener() but it isnt possible unlike in activities were it is. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

YourActivity.this.getActivity().startSearch();
this may work!